# Bluetooth on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bluetooth, services, blueman, bluez

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my ASUS S200e laptop.
Everything is working except the bluetooth - I cannot get my mouse connected.

When I try to open `Blueman`, I get:

```
"Bluez daemon not running"
```

When I run `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` output is:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [1a3b:2107]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 03eb:8417 Atmel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b3d8 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Answer (score 14):

Depending exactly what the issue is, there are a bunch of options.  Here are a few.

**1.  Start the bluetooth daemon**

Go to your terminal and type :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
```

**2.  Reinstall packages**

If this doesn't work, go to your terminal and type :

```
sudo apt-get purge blueman bluez-utils bluez bluetooth
sudo apt-get install blueman bluez-utils bluez bluetooth
```

Then run :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
```

Comment: ~$ sudo apt-get install blueman bluez-utils bluez bluetooth
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package bluez-utils is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  bluez:i386 bluez

E: Package 'bluez-utils' has no installation candidate

Comment: Okay, repeat the commands without the `bluez-utils`.

Comment: OK - now the blueman program runs, but the buttons are greyed out. When you click adapter/device - activate, nothing happens

Comment: Do you have a bluetooth switch on your laptop?  If so, try switching it off and then on again.

Comment: Could also try running `sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth`.

Comment: Or `sudo hciconfig hci0 reset`.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this:   "sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth" - this does nothing;   "sudo hciconfig hci0 reset" returns Can't get device info. No such device

Comment: Interestingly, my wifi is gone now as well...

Comment: Have you restarted your computer?  Sometimes it can be as simple as that...

Comment: I have restared, yes

Comment: I also see that when I try to run Unity Tweak tool, I get the error "The following schema is missing: com.canonical.indicator.bluetooth"

Comment: UPDATE: I managed to fix the wireless by running Synaptic and installing/fixing the packages under CUSTOM FILTERS -  MISSING RECCOMENDS

Comment: So now it's just the bluetooth not working. Bluetooth Manager says: "NO adapters found"

Answer (score 12):

i did the purge command already mentioned:

```
sudo apt-get purge blueman bluez-utils bluez bluetooth
```

but modified the install command like below

```
sudo apt-get install blueman bluez:i386 bluetooth
```

My settings icon is now missing but when I searched for bluetooth it prompted me to enable it and it now seems to work

I went back and reinstalled the other packages the purge removed:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth* ubuntu-desktop* unity-control-center*
```

The abovecommand reinstalled the settings that had been uninstalled but bluetooth not connecting to my device. To be continued...

Comment: This post helped me resolve the last part https://askubuntu.com/questions/801404/bluetooth-connection-failed-blueman-bluez-errors-dbusfailederror-protocol-no

Comment: wait, so, after the first part, bleutooth was working, but too much stuff was purged; and then, when you reinstalled that stuff, it broke again?

Comment: I ended up getting it working but the lag in sound vs video made it pointless. I put it out of my mind after that so I cant offer any further info...

Comment: I got my Microsoft designer keyboard and mouse working wonderfully on Ubuntu 16.04 running on an Asus Vivobook. See my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1023532/815371 (hope this helps someone)

Comment: Works great. ty!!

Answer (score 0):

just replace the bluez-utils with bluez:i386 like so
$sudo apt-get install blueman bluez:i386 bluetooth
after then run the launch
$sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
 (Then it'll read out)

[ ok ] Starting bluetooth (via systemctl): bluetooth.service.

if you still don't see your device in the bluetooth pairing settings then your device's architecture just isn't built with the bluetooth setting available