# Bluetooth - Connection Failed: blueman.bluez.errors.DBusFailedError: Protocol Not available

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headset, bluez

I'm trying to add a BlueParrott B-250XT+ bluetooth headset on a Thinkpad X230 tablet running Ubuntu 16.04 with its hardware bluetooth adapter.

The adapter works - meaning it detects/sees the headset. However, when connecting to the headset it initially connects, then this error pops up:

```
Connection Failed: blueman.bluez.errors.DBusFailedError: Protocol Not available
```

Afterwards, the Headset disconnects and future connections are impossible - this is some sort of failure/error that causes the bluetooth to be unresponsive afterwards.

I have Pulseaudio installed and I have bluetooth set to load after X11 (this is what got me this far - to the point I can connect). But, as mentioned, the device gets dumped shortly after connection.

Comment: same problem here. I have a fresh xubuntu installation on my dell latitude e6410 laptop. Trying to connect to JBL Charge3 speaker. The device was paired, but i can connect only to serial port. When Try to connect to audio sink or headset I get Connection Failed: blueman.bluez.errors.DBusFailedError: Protocol not available

Comment: I advice to try on a (live) Ubuntu 15.10 first, so that you can have an idea if the problem is in the BT stack version. Ubuntu 16.04 had a bluetooth stack update which significantly broke BT functionality.

Comment: That is a really good idea! I will try some live CDs when I have the time. Thanks,

Comment: Note that on ArchLinux the package to install is named `pulseaudio-bluetooth` instead of `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`. Just leaving a note here since this is the first result that comes up in the Google search.

Answer (score 181):

The solution from [this article](https://zach-adams.com/2014/07/bluetooth-audio-sink-stream-setup-failed/) worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

Then delete the device from bluetooth devices and pair it again.

If it works, you can consider adding the second command to your startup settings, so that you don't have to run it again after every reboot.

---

If it doesn't work, try restarting `pulseaudio`:

```
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio -D
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I get a message 'Failure: Module initialization failed' when I do step 2 so it doesn't work for me yet.

Comment: Worked for me, but I need to do that every time I reboot...

Comment: Worked on Xubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo G580. If you are hearing the sound through the laptop speakers after successfully pairing it, try changing the profile at Volume Control -> Configuration -> Built-in Audio.

Comment: Thanks man. Worked for me on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with Sony MDR-XB70BT

Comment: It worked for me (Nokia BH-503). Thank you very much.

Comment: Has anyone found a more permanent solution for this yet?

Comment: Worked for Jabra revo

Comment: [Here is another post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/259354/how-do-i-connect-to-my-bluetooth-headset) in addition to @lepe's comment

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu Studio 16.10 with a UE Mobile Boombox. Thanks!

Comment: Worked on my MPOW-059 with xubuntu 16.10

Comment: @psedach, be aware that message will show if one attempts to load the module when it's already loaded. You can test whether it's loaded with `pactl list | grep module-bluetooth-discover`.

Comment: Worked for me (JBL E50BT)

Comment: Step 1 only worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: For me the solution did not work

Comment: root@localhost:~# pactl list
Verbindungsfehler: Verbindung verweigert
pa_context_new() fehlgeschlagen: Verbindung verweigert

Comment: My default pulse configuration file `/etc/pulse/default.pa` there was already the configuration line in there. `.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so \n
load-module module-bluetooth-discover \n
.endif` On the next startup, it worked out-of-the-box. (`\n` added to symbolise linebreaks that were there)

Comment: @IanMackinnon - `that message will show if one attempts to load the module when it's already loaded` - in which case what is the path to follow? I cannot make it work at this point unless I restart or reinstall bluez. If I delete the device it is not seen again until reboot or bluez-reinstall. (In my case this mostly appears after logging out.)

Comment: A way to make this change permanent is in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/689297/456247)

Comment: This answer doesn't work. On Ubuntu, it just gives me `Failure: Module initialization failed` and `E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.`

Comment: Brilliant - yes thanks - works fine on Lubuntu 18.04  with kernel 4.15:    I found this AFTER doing an upgrade of the bluetooth itself which made no difference at all - staggering that a dependency like this can be left missing.

Answer (score 5):

What did work for me was this: (as pointed above by Sebastian Widz)

```
$ sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio  
$ rm ~/.config/pulse && sudo killall pulseaudio  
$ sudo apt-get install pulseaudio  
$ pulseaudio --start
```

The above to ensure pulse is working first.
Then, this one, which is a bit weird that doesn't come by default with pulseaudio itself:

```
$ sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth  
$ pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

A bit redundant I know, but these were the exact steps that worked for me 10 minutes ago.
But OK, at least it works now :)

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! It seems that sometime pulse's configs get messed up preventing connection to my BT headsets.

Comment: Worked for me in Xubuntu 21.10.