# how to connect a multifunction speaker to ubuntu 16.04 via bluetooth?

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, broadcom

I recently bought a multifunction speaker, which can connect using bluetooth. The device is listed as S2025 in bluetooth settings (see the image below), but the connection is greyed out (OFF). The speakers usually sound **"Bluetooth connected"** when connected using android smartphone it functions properly. I have already tried a few things searching solution to similar question on askubuntu such as installing bluez:i386 package.

[image]

Following is the output of some of the commands in terminal

**rfkill list**

```
0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**dmesg | grep Blue**

```
[    2.223104] usb 2-1.6: Product: Askey Bluetooth Module
[   10.202779] toshiba_bluetooth: Toshiba ACPI Bluetooth device driver
[   12.364366] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   12.364390] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   12.364395] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   12.364399] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   12.364406] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   23.368259] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   23.368263] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   23.368268] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   91.485956] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   91.485965] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   91.485972] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  786.527268] usb 2-1.6: Product: Askey Bluetooth Module
```

**lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb**

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Askey Computer Corp. BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [144f:7175]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0930:0214 Toshiba Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b28e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52e Logitech, Inc. MK260 Wireless Combo Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Open up the bluetooth  panel indicator drop down. If the speaker is listed mouse over it.  'Uncover ' the On button (- click on where it is). Does the connection stay on & work?

Comment: I can turn it on via bluetooth panel indicator drop down, but it doesn't work, the connection setting inside the bluetooth dialog also remains OFF

Comment: Try opening bluetooth settings, remove the speaker. Then add it back, close settings, open the indicator & try to connect again.  Don't try to connect thru Bluetooth settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps resolved the problem:

1. Install proprietary driver for the Broadcom BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter under `Additional Drivers` tab of `Software & Updates`.
2. From terminal run `pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover` as suggested in reply to [this askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801404/bluetooth-connection-failed-blueman-bluez-errors-dbusfailederror-protocol-no)
3. Remove the device and pair it again in bluetooth manager

Hope it helps others having similar problem.