# LXQt/Lubuntu 19.10 has no bluetooth panel indicator

Tags: lubuntu, bluetooth, 19.10, lxqt

When recently installing Lubuntu 19.10 I notice there is no bluetooth **indicator** present, although `bluedevil` is installed and I can run "Bluedevil Wizard". In order to get an indicator I have installed `blueman`.  Am I supposed to do that and not have a bluetooth indicator by default?

(By the way, this 18.10 problem still affects me in 19.10: [Bluetooth connection (Bluez) not working after logout (works after restart)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1088277/925128). In the context of that question - different from this one as it may be: with just `bluedevil` I cannot even see my bluetooth device and cannot add it at all. I need `blueman` to see and add the device, and then reinstall `bluez` or restart when the linked problem appears.)

Comment: https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/2/2.1/2.1.4/bluedevil.html  *Bluedevil is the default application to manage Bluetooth devices for Lubuntu.*   (I don't use bluetooth, but I have an applet on my panel for bluetooth in the System.Tray)  https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/lubuntu-desktop shows `bluedevil`is installed by default

Comment: @guiverc - I will make clear in the question body just like in the title: I too have bluedevil but starting it brings no  Bluetooth *indicator* to the panel.

Answer (score 8):

Just install `Bluetooth Manager`:

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

and go to `Start` -> `Bluetooth Manager`.

**Also works fine for `Lubuntu 20.04`**.

Comment: The same solution is for Lubuntu 21.04

Comment: minor correction - at least in LXDE (plain, no QT, not the Lubuntu session which both didnt work well for me) it is: 
Start -> Preferences -> Bluetooth Manager  (one more menu level)