# Bluetooth headset pairs successfully, but does not play audio (18.04)

Tags: 18.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, bluez

I'm trying to connect a bluetooth headset (Insignia NS-CAHBTEB01-B) to my computer, which is running an up-to-date install of Kubuntu 18.04. Everything seems to go smoothly at first -- I am able to pair the headset successfully using the "Bluetooth Devices" System Settings module GUI -- but the headset doesn't play audio output from the computer. Some things I have noticed:

- I can tell the headset has paired successfully because I hear "Your device is connected" through the headphones. Also, pressing the play/pause button while watching a video in VLC will sometimes cause it to play or pause (not reliably), and using `pacmd` to change the active profile to `headset_head_unit` causes the headset to vibrate (see below).
- The headset shows up in the "Audio Volume" widget in the system tray and in system settings. I can try to adjust the volume -- when I do this, I hear a faint hissing noise through the headphones. It persists for a second or two after I stop adjusting the volume slider, and then cuts off.
- Running `pacmd list-cards` gives the following output (in part):

```
    index: 4
        name: <bluez_card.E8_07_BF_02_3C_F1>
        driver: <module-bluez5-device.c>
        owner module: 28
        properties:
                device.description = "NS-CAHBTEB01"
                device.string = "E8:07:BF:02:3C:F1"
                device.api = "bluez"
                device.class = "sound"
                device.bus = "bluetooth"
                device.form_factor = "headset"
                bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_E8_07_BF_02_3C_F1"
                bluez.class = "0x240404"
                bluez.alias = "NS-CAHBTEB01"
                device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
                device.intended_roles = "phone"
        profiles:
                a2dp_sink: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink) (priority 40, available: unknown)
                headset_head_unit: Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) (priority 30, available: unknown)
                off: Off (priority 0, available: yes)
        active profile: <a2dp_sink>
        sinks:
                bluez_sink.E8_07_BF_02_3C_F1.a2dp_sink/#6: NS-CAHBTEB01
        sources:
                bluez_sink.E8_07_BF_02_3C_F1.a2dp_sink.monitor/#9: Monitor of NS-CAHBTEB01
        ports:
                headset-output: Headset (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                        properties:

                headset-input: Headset (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                        properties:
```

I can then run `pacmd set-card-profile 4 headset_head_unit` and `pacmd set-card-profile 4 a2dp_sink` to switch back and forth between the `headset_head_unit` and `a2dp_sink` profiles, which seems to be successful (changes the `active_profile` line above and causes the headset to buzz when I switch to `headset_head_unit`), but doesn't get me sound out of the headphones.

Solutions I have ruled out:

- Just rebooting the computer doesn't seem to help.
- The `bluez`, `pulseaudio`, and `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` packages are all installed and at the latest versions. I've also tried installing `blueman` and `pavucontrol`, with no immediate results (I got the impression these are just GTK GUIs whose functionality is duplicated by KDE, but maybe I'm wrong).
- I've looked at some posts here ([Blueman Protocol not available](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115671/blueman-protocol-not-available), [After updating to 16.04, bluetooth audio A2DP mode stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775523/after-updating-to-16-04-bluetooth-audio-a2dp-mode-stopped-working)) and on the Arch Linux forums (https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1526534#p1526534). These lead me to suspect that the culprit might be something to do with `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf` or the PulseAudio module `module-bluetooth-discover`. I tried following the steps in Rmano's answer at [After updating to 16.04, bluetooth audio A2DP mode stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775523/after-updating-to-16-04-bluetooth-audio-a2dp-mode-stopped-working), but it didn't work for me. Some people also suggested switching to HSP/HFP mode, disconnecting, reconnecting, and switching back to A2DP mode, but I think this is the same as what I did above with `pacmd`, which didn't work.

The only evidence I've found of something going wrong, other than the lack of audio playing through the headphones, is the fact that running `pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover` gives the error `Failure: Module initialization failed`. I'm not sure what's causing this.

How can I get my headset to play audio?

Comment: Are you running HWE and the later 18.04 stack? or the original one?  KDE/Kubuntu uses `pavucontrol-qt` by default (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/kubuntu-desktop); have you tried using that to select your desired output device?  (*you only mentioning install `pavucontrol` and not using it to change settings*)

Comment: `pavucontrol-qt` is installed and at the latest version. The headset shows up, and I can do the same switching between HSP/HFP and A2DP modes that I did using `pacmd`, with the same results. The headset shows up as "locked together" with the built-in audio and also "set as fallback". I'm not sure if there's another setting I can change to select the headset.

Comment: How do I find out if I'm running HWE?

Comment: HWE is enabled if you installed using 18.04.2 or later media, or enabled it (if older media was used); but the kernel used is probably the fastest (`uname -a`) or you could ask your system (`hwe-support-status --verbose`).  Non-HWE will mean the 4.15 kernel is being used, HWE means your kernel & part of software-stack got updated to 18.10/19.04/19.10 eventually landing on 20.04 (useful for later hardware support esp. graphics; https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).  With `pavucontrol` I'd hoped "*Output Devices*" or "*Configuration*" would be helpful.

Comment: "Output Devices" and "Configuration" are exactly where I looked in `pavucontrol` -- I found the device and the "lock together" and "set as fallback" settings in "Output Devices", and the option to switch between HSP/HFP and A2DP in "Configuration".

Comment: I'm running kernel 4.20.7, but that's because I had to update the kernel to get the appropriate graphics drivers when I first installed Kubuntu (this is a Hades Canyon NUC, which has Vega M graphics).

Comment: According to `hwe-support-status --verbose`, I am not running a system with a Hardware Enablement Stack.

Comment: Kernel 4.20 is EOL & hasn't got loads of patches/backports, in fact is *out-of-stream* for Ubuntu (never going beyond test). Kernels 4.15 or 5.0 are the standard kernels so I'd suggest trying one of the supported Ubuntu 18.04 kernels  (5.0 if you don't want 4.15; if that works you revert to standard kernel, enable HWE & it'll upgrade to 5.3 automatically).

Comment: OK, I've installed the HWE packages and now I'm on kernel 5.0. This hasn't solved the problem, but it has made a difference -- now connecting the headset doesn't seem to work, but visibly fails. Trying to pair via system settings gives me "The setup of NS-CAHBTEB01 has failed." Using `bluetoothctl` as described on the ArchWiki (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_headset) gives me an "org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists" (for some reason).

Comment: What I'm getting now is different enough that maybe I should ask a follow-up question later, rather than trying to edit this one.