# bluetooth headphones stopped working after updating to 21.10

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, 21.10

After updating to 21.10 today i cant pair and connect my bluetooth headphones (Sony WH-1000XM4), bluetooth itself is working as i can connect and use a bluetooth mouse. The headphones worked flawlessly before the update. I use kde on x11 as my de. I've tried to sudo systemctl restart bluetooth to no effect. Is there a way to get them to work again?

edit: bluetoothctl actually shows that i can pair the headphones but connecting fails with an error:org.bluez.Error.Failed

Comment: What sound server you use: pulseaudio or pipewire (check `pactl info` output)

Comment: @pasmanpasmański i use pulseaudio

Comment: WH1000XM2 works on Ubuntu (gnome de). Maybe you should repeat pair+trust steps ?

Comment: already done that a few times, does not seem to work, in bluetoothctl everything seems fine but it just does not connect, when i try to do that i get protocol not available error

Comment: You may check installed packages : `apt list --installed '*blue*'` , compare with https://pastebin.com/u713BDgx

Comment: here's the output:
bluedevil
bluez-cups
bluez-obexd/impish,now 5.60-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
bluez/impish,now 5.60-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0/impish,now 3.34.5-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-bluetooth/impish,now 3.34.5-3 amd64 [installed]
libbluetooth3/impish,now 5.60-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgnome-bluetooth13/impish,now 3.34.5-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libkf5bluezqt-data/impish,impish,now 5.86.0-0ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
libkf5bluezqt6/
qml-module-org-kde-bluezqt

Had to delete a few links cuz they wouldnt fit

Comment: pulseaudio-module-bluetooth is in it ?

Comment: wasnt there, installed it and restarted bluetooth but it didnt fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same problem that you are describing, also after upgrade to 21.10. For me, the solution described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/801669/585855) worked, except the module was already there so I had to `--reinstall`:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

Then remove and pair the device again.

Comment: thank you so much, worked like a charm