# Bluetooth headphones cannot connect after update to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04, headphones

After I updated Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04, my system cannot connect to my Huawei Freebuds 3 bluetooth headphones anymore. When I click on the headphones in the devices list, it tries to connect for a while, until it stops. I already removed the device and tried to pair again, but with the same result.

I tried to establish an connection on the command-line via `bluetoothctl` as described in [this blog article](https://www.nielsvandermolen.com/bluetooth-headphones-ubuntu/), but the result is the same, and it doesn't report any error. Is there a command-line tool for bluetooth that actually outputs a useful log/error message?

Furthermore, I tried [this suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/1369477/515475), but after re-installing pulseaudio-module-bluetooth, `sudo pactl https://askubuntu.com/a/1369477/515475` reports the error

```
Connection error: Connection refused
pa_context_new() failed: Connection refused
```

`pactl list modules` shows:

```
Module #10
    Name: module-bluetooth-discover
    Argument: 
    Usage count: k. A.
    Properties:
        module.author = "João Paulo Rechi Vita"
        module.description = "Detect available Bluetooth daemon and load the corresponding discovery module"
        module.version = "15.99.1"

Module #11
    Name: module-bluez5-discover
    Argument: 
    Usage count: k. A.
    Properties:
        module.author = "João Paulo Rechi Vita"
        module.description = "Detect available BlueZ 5 Bluetooth audio devices and load BlueZ 5 Bluetooth audio drivers"
        module.version = "15.99.1"
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just managed to solve it. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1369477/515475) was almost the solution to my problem. After re-installing the module, I should first *unload* the module, before loading it again. Furthermore, I shouldn't have used `sudo`, this doesn't need root permission.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
pactl unload-module module-bluetooth-discover
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

Comment: Thanks, that saved my life :)

Comment: I tried the second part but I got the error:
`Failed to unload module: Module module-bluetooth-discover not loaded`

Comment: The module isn't loaded, so you don't have to unload it. Skip that line and try the third command instead.

Comment: I tried the third one and I get `pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
` when I do `sudo` and `Failure: No such entity` without `sudo`

Comment: I get `Failure: No such entity` too

Comment: same issue here:

~$ pactl unload-module module-bluetooth-discover
Failed to unload module: Module module-bluetooth-discover not loaded
~$ pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
Failure: No such entity

Comment: this solution worked very well for me with ubuntu 22.04 and Huwawei freebuds pro 2. Thank you, you saved my day

Comment: On a fresh install of Ubuntu 23.04, I installed `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` successfully, then got the error `Failed to unload module: Module module-bluetooth-discover not loaded` on the second command and  `Failure: No such entity` on the third. However, I could connect to the headphones nonetheless. Maybe the second and third command aren't always needed.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer doesn't work for me. My headphone is Beats Studio 3. I installed blueman, but it still fails to pair.

I finally solved the problem by changing the visibility setting provided by blueman to always visible.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to press the Play/Pause button after you pair the system and the device. This will make the gnome sound manager have the A2DP available. With this option on you can easily set the audio output in the menu. Although this solution isn’t ideal, it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Working with a Kinesis Advantage 360 Pro keyboard, I found out that the bluetooth profile did not clean itself up after a manual disconnect.  I had to "clear" the bluetooth profile from the device.  It immediately attempted a re-connection and worked.