Can't connect to bluetooth ubuntu 22.04
I recently installed ubuntu 22.04 LTS and my earphone will not connect. bluetooth is working as it can show my devices but it will not connect.
I have tried reinstalling the bluez package and also tried restarting the bluetooth service multiple time
my bluetooth is working fine in windows and it was also working fine in Ubuntu 24.04
here is the output of systemctl status bluetooth
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-07-05 22:31:03 IST; 9min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 7144 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18294)
     Memory: 856.0K
        CPU: 78ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─7144 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jul 05 22:31:03 reacher bluetoothd[7144]: Failed to add UUID: Failed (0x03)
Jul 05 22:31:03 reacher bluetoothd[7144]: Failed to add UUID: Failed (0x03)
Jul 05 22:31:03 reacher bluetoothd[7144]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.94 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Jul 05 22:31:03 reacher bluetoothd[7144]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.94 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Jul 05 22:31:03 reacher bluetoothd[7144]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.94 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_453
Jul 05 22:31:03 reacher bluetoothd[7144]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.94 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_453
Jul 05 22:31:03 reacher bluetoothd[7144]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.94 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_512
Jul 05 22:31:03 reacher bluetoothd[7144]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.94 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_512
Jul 05 22:31:03 reacher bluetoothd[7144]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.94 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
Jul 05 22:31:03 reacher bluetoothd[7144]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.94 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552
~

And here is the output of sudo journalctl  -b 0 | grep "Bluetooth"
Jul 06 02:47:00 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
Jul 06 02:47:00 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Jul 06 02:47:00 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Jul 06 02:47:00 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Jul 06 02:47:00 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
Jul 06 02:47:23 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.3 build 0 week 24 2017
Jul 06 02:47:23 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 1
Jul 06 02:47:23 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
Jul 06 02:47:23 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
Jul 06 02:47:23 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
Jul 06 02:47:23 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
Jul 06 02:47:23 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
Jul 06 02:47:23 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-20-1-3.sfi
Jul 06 02:47:23 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Boot Address: 0x24800
Jul 06 02:47:23 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware Version: 126-5.22
Jul 06 02:47:23 reacher systemd[1]: Reached target Bluetooth Support.
Jul 06 02:47:24 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
Jul 06 02:47:24 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1748173 usecs
Jul 06 02:47:24 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
Jul 06 02:47:24 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 14894 usecs
Jul 06 02:47:24 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
Jul 06 02:47:24 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-20-1-3.ddc
Jul 06 02:47:24 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
Jul 06 02:47:24 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.3 build 126 week 5 2022
Jul 06 02:47:24 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: HCI LE Coded PHY feature bit is set, but its usage is not supported.
Jul 05 21:18:41 reacher systemd[1656]: Starting Bluetooth OBEX service...
Jul 05 21:18:41 reacher systemd[1656]: Started Bluetooth OBEX service.
Jul 05 21:21:22 reacher systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jul 05 21:21:22 reacher bluetoothd[5309]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
Jul 05 21:21:22 reacher systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jul 05 21:21:22 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Jul 05 21:21:22 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Jul 05 21:21:22 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Jul 05 21:21:22 reacher bluetoothd[5309]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
Jul 05 21:21:22 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
Jul 05 21:21:25 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Jul 05 21:21:25 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Jul 05 21:21:25 reacher kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11


This may help https://askubuntu.com/questions/1439523/bluetooth-headphones-cannot-connect-after-update-to-ubuntu-22-04

Try with installing Blueman.  It is in the repository.µ

Hey i installed blueman but it's still not working for me

When you run blueman can you see  your headphone? If yes, click on it, and connect manually.  If not, is your headphone ready to connect, or connect with some other phone-tablet-pc ....).   Thanks for the downvote of my answer!
