# Bluetooth doesn't work on laptop with ubuntu 16

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, laptop

I have Ubuntu 16.04 running on a sony vaio PCG61611U laptop.

I try to use bluetooth but it doesn't work.

`lsmod |grep bluetooth`

```
bluetooth             557056  9 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,btusb

lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. T77H126.00 802.11bgn Wireless Half-size Mini PCIe Card [105b:e017]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 13ee:0001 MosArt Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub...
```

I've tried [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776806/bluetooth-on-ubuntu-16-04) but it doesn't work yet.

Comment: Check the BIOS. It may be disabled there. I do not see a BT device in lsusb.

Answer (score 1):

Some Atheros wireless cards do not have the bluetooth option.  If you can access the card by removing a panel on the bottom, the model number will tell you if it has bluetooth or not
[image: Atheros AR9285]

The picture shows a model Atheros AR5B195 and this model has bluetooth, if your card shows AR5B95 then it will not have bluetooth.  The picture shows both a MAC ID for wireless and BD ID for bluetooth.  I have an Azurewave AR5B195 and the sticker is on the back side of the card