# Bluetooth not discovering any devices - Dell XPS 13 (16.04)

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, dell

I have looked at other solutions and threads for this problem but none of them have worked for me. I am using a Dell XPS 13 to connect my new Jaybird X3 earphones. So far, the laptop has been unable to detect neither my earphones nor my mobile device.

EDIT: All the devices are on discoverable mode. I've tried reinstalling Bluetooth using this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/776812/701563 and it did not work. I'm not sure why, but now BLueman Assistant says "No adaptors found".

I ran some commands in terminal and these are the results:

$ sudo service bluetooth status

```
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-07-19 10:46:20 AEST; 3min 30s ago
 Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
Main PID: 1210 (bluetoothd)
Status: "Running"
CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
        └─1210 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jul 19 10:46:20 fsc0ciety systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jul 19 10:46:20 fsc0ciety bluetoothd[1210]: Bluetooth daemon 5.37
Jul 19 10:46:20 fsc0ciety bluetoothd[1210]: Unknown key AutoEnable in main.conf
Jul 19 10:46:20 fsc0ciety systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jul 19 10:46:20 fsc0ciety bluetoothd[1210]: Starting SDP server
Jul 19 10:46:20 fsc0ciety bluetoothd[1210]: Bluetooth management interface 1.13 
Jul 19 10:49:35 fsc0ciety systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
```

$ rfkill list

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

$ lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:5682 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f3:20d0 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:216f Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

$ uname -a; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware; lsmod | grep bluetoothLinux

```
Linux fsc0ciety 4.8.0-58-generic #63~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 18:08:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Dell BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0019]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:5682 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f3:20d0 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:216f Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    6.939516] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    6.939535] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    6.939539] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    6.939541] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    6.939546] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    7.074389] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
[    7.090392] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A
[    7.091389] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
[    8.736332] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    8.736333] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    8.736337] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    9.184663] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x213c tx timeout
[   17.376813] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch command 213c failed (-110)
[   19.392869] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c03 tx timeout
[   27.617047] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reset failed (-110)
[   29.633143] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c03 tx timeout
[   37.857308] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reset failed (-110)
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Are the devices in discoverable mode?

Comment: @Bex please see the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to finally fix this issue thanks to this answer:
https://askubuntu.com/a/920803/701563

**Step 1** - List your usb devices

```
lsusb
```

(Displayed this for Bluetooth for me)

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0a5c:216f Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth
```

**Step 2** - Go to https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/tree/master/brcm to download the converted driver that matches your ID from above. For me this was ***BCM20702A1-0a5c-216f.hcd*** (Click on the file to download it)

**Step 3** - Copy the downloaded file to `/lib/firmware/brcm`

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo cp BCM20702A1-0a5c-216f.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm
```

**Step 4** - Reboot. Bluetooth should be working now.

---

If you get this error while connecting your Bluetooth Audio device:

```
Connection Failed: blueman.bluez.errors.DBusFailedError: Protocol Not available
```

Solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/801669/701563

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

And then, delete the device from bluetooth devices and pair it again.

Hopefully this helps you connect your Bluetooth audio devices.

Comment: I was trying to connect my Dell XPS 13 (9343) running *Ubuntu 16.04* to a JBL Go bluetooth speaker. I was able to find the device, but I couldn't even get it to pair. This was exactly what I was looking for and solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: I did not find my ID ,the result of my bluetooth is : `Bus 003 Device 008: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)`