# Bluetooth doesnt discover any nearby devices

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

This what i get when i tried running this command:

```
dmesg | grep -i 'blue'

[   15.207462] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   15.207500] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   15.207504] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   15.207506] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   15.207509] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   16.680022] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   16.681193] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[   16.697041] Bluetooth: hci0: Stryker
[   16.697047] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[   16.932675] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware Patch file not found, tried:
[   16.932681] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd'
[   16.932684] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM-0a5c-21d7.hcd'
[   18.962893] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   18.964047] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[   35.728986] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   35.728988] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   35.728992] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   38.802234] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   38.803057] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[  157.117857] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  157.117866] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  157.117874] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 1203.836728] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000003f75a935 failed to resubmit (2)
[ 1226.691458] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[ 1226.692517] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[ 1226.708496] Bluetooth: hci0: Stryker
[ 1226.708504] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[ 1226.709489] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware Patch file not found, tried:
[ 1226.709493] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd'
[ 1226.709495] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM-0a5c-21d7.hcd'
[ 1228.733520] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[ 1228.734487] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
```

(Any help is appreciated). Bluetooth works but doesnt detect any devices.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  
I just had to download a driver and place it in the required folder. 
Here is the link that I followed : [Bluetooth not discovering any devices - Dell XPS 13 (16.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/937320/bluetooth-not-discovering-any-devices-dell-xps-13-16-04?rq=1)

Hope it helps you :) .